# Implementing a remove method in a java Hashmap?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

So a hashmap is a hash-based implementation of a map structure in java. I've figured out how to get the hashmap put method to work, but I want to write a method that removes the key value pair, and I'm having trouble implementing it.

The only thing I can really understand right now is how to tell the function to stop in the event that the key is empty or doesn't exist.. I'd love any sort of help. An explanation as to how the method will work, or some basic pseudo-code examples would be much appreciated.

This is what I have in the delete method so far:

```
public void delete(K key) {  
        if (key == null) {  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null Key!");
        }

        // Implement this method

    }
```

If it helps, here is my completed Map Entry class:

```
public class MapEntry<K, V> {

    MapEntry<K, V> next;  
    K key;  
    V value;  

    public MapEntry(K key, V value) {  
        this.setKey(key);  
        this.setValue(value);  
    }  

    public void setKey(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {  
        this.value = value;  
    }  

    public K getKey() {  
        return key;  
    }  

    public V getValue() {  
        return value;  
    }  

    public void setNext(MapEntry<K, V> next) {  
        this.next = next;  
    }  

    public MapEntry<K, V> getNext() {  
        return next;  
    }   

}
```

Also, here's the entirety of my HashMap class if it helps.

```
public class HashMap<K, V> {

    private int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;  
    private MapEntry<K, V>[] Hash;  
    private int size;

    public HashMap() {  
        Hash = new MapEntry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];  
    }  

    public int getHashCode(K key) {  
        int bucketIndex = key.hashCode() % Hash.length;  
        return bucketIndex;  
    }  

    public V get(K key) {  
        if (key == null) {  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null Key!");
        }
        MapEntry<K, V> entry = Hash[getHashCode(key)];  
        while (entry != null && !key.equals(entry.getKey()))   
            entry = entry.getNext();  
        if (entry != null)
            return entry.getValue();
        else
            return null;
    }  

 /**
  * 
  * @param key
  * @param value
  * The put method works by associating the specified value with
  * the given key in the map. 
  * If the key is already in the map, 
  * the old value is replaced with the new one. 
  */


    public void put(K key, V value) {
        int keyBucket = hash(key);

        MapEntry<K, V> temp = Hash[keyBucket];
        while (temp != null) {
            if ((temp.key == null && key == null) 
                    || (temp.key != null && temp.key.equals(key))) {
                temp.value = value;
                return;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        Hash[keyBucket] = new MapEntry<K, V>(key, value);
        size++;
    }

    public void delete(K key) {  
        if (key == null) {  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null Key!");
        }

        // Implement this method

    }  


    public void print(){
        //Bonus Method
    }

    private int hash(K key) {
        if (key == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Math.abs(key.hashCode() % this.Hash.length);
        }

}   }
```

Comment: Given you are copying a built in class which works, I suggest you learn more by reading this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same logic that you do in `get()`, locate the correct bucket and, within that bucket, the correct `MapEntry` (let's call it `e`). Then simply remove `e` from the bucket—basically, this is removing a node from a single-linked list. If `e` is the first element in the bucket, set the corresponding element of `Hash` to `e.next`; otherwise set the `next` field of the element just before `e` to `e.next`. Note that you need one more variable (updated as you're finding `e`) to keep track of the previous entry in the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

[source code](https://github.com/ReuvenEliezer/Interviews-Questions/blob/master/src/main/java/MyInternalMap.java)

```
public class MyInternalMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266459/implementing-a-remove-method-in-a-java-hashmap
 */


private final int initialCapacity;
private MyMapEntry<K, V>[] mapEntries;
private int size;

public MyInternalMap() {
    this(16);
}

public MyInternalMap(int initialCapacity) {
    this.initialCapacity = initialCapacity;
    mapEntries = new MyMapEntry[initialCapacity];
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

@Override
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return get(key) != null;
}

@Override
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mapEntries.length; i++) {
        MyMapEntry<K, V> mapEntry = mapEntries[i];
        if (containsValue(value, mapEntry)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean containsValue(Object value, MyMapEntry<K, V> mapEntry) {
    if (mapEntry == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (value == mapEntry.getValue() || mapEntry.getValue().equals(value)) {
        return true;
    }
    return containsValue(value, mapEntry.next);
}

@Override
public V get(Object key) {
    if (key == null) {
        return null;
    }
    MyMapEntry<K, V> entry = mapEntries[getHashCode(key)];
    while (entry != null) {
        if (key.equals(entry.key)) {
            return entry.value;
        }
        entry = entry.next;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public V put(K key, V value) {
    int keyBucket = getHashCode(key);

    MyMapEntry<K, V> temp = mapEntries[keyBucket];
    if (temp == null) {
        //create new head node in this bucket
        mapEntries[keyBucket] = new MyMapEntry<>(key, value);
        size++;
        return null;
    }
    while (temp != null) {
        if ((temp.key == null && key == null)
                || (temp.key != null && temp.key.equals(key))) {
            V returnValue = temp.value;
            temp.value = value;
            return returnValue;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    //create new node in this bucket
    mapEntries[keyBucket].next = new MyMapEntry<>(key, value);
    size++;
    return null;
}

@Override
public V remove(Object key) {
    /**
     * Using the same logic that you do in get(), locate the correct bucket and, within that bucket, the correct MapEntry (let's call it e). Then simply remove e from the bucket—basically,
     * this is removing a node from a single-linked list. If e is the first element in the bucket, set the corresponding element of Hash to e.next;
     * otherwise set the next field of the element just before e to e.next. Note that you need one more variable (updated as you're finding e) to keep track of the previous entry in the bucket
     */
    int keyBucket = getHashCode(key);
    MyMapEntry<K, V> temp = mapEntries[keyBucket];
    if (temp == null)
        return null;
    MyMapEntry<K, V> prev = temp;
    while (temp != null) {
        if (temp.key != null && temp.key.equals(key)) {
            V valueReturn = temp.value;
            if (prev == temp) { //first element?
                mapEntries[keyBucket] = temp.next;
            } else {
                prev.next = temp.next;
            }
            size--;
            return valueReturn;
        }
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
    //TODO impl
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    mapEntries = new MyMapEntry[initialCapacity];
    size = 0;
}

@Override
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> resultKeys = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mapEntries.length; i++) {
        MyMapEntry<K, V> mapEntry = mapEntries[i];
        addKeySet(mapEntry, resultKeys);
    }
    return resultKeys;
}

private void addKeySet(MyMapEntry<K, V> mapEntry, Set<K> resultKeys) {
    if (mapEntry != null) {
        resultKeys.add(mapEntry.key);
        addKeySet(mapEntry.next, resultKeys);
    }
}

@Override
public Collection<V> values() {
    Collection<V> resultValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mapEntries.length; i++) {
        MyMapEntry<K, V> mapEntry = mapEntries[i];
        addValue(mapEntry, resultValues);
    }
    return resultValues;
}

private void addValue(MyMapEntry<K, V> mapEntry, Collection<V> resultValues) {
    if (mapEntry != null) {
        resultValues.add(mapEntry.value);
        addValue(mapEntry.next, resultValues);
    }
}

@Override
public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySetResult = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mapEntries.length; i++) {
        MyMapEntry<K, V> mapEntry = mapEntries[i];
        addEntrySet(mapEntry, entrySetResult);
    }
    return entrySetResult;
}

private void addEntrySet(MyMapEntry<K, V> mapEntry, Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySetResult) {
    if (mapEntry != null) {
        entrySetResult.add(mapEntry);
        addEntrySet(mapEntry.next, entrySetResult);
    }
}

private int getHashCode(Object key) {
    if (key == null)
        return 0;
    int bucketIndex = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % initialCapacity;
    return bucketIndex;
}


class MyMapEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
    private K key;
    private V value;
    private MyMapEntry<K, V> next;

    public MyMapEntry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V setValue(V value) {
        V oldValue = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        return oldValue;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class MyInternalMapTest {

@ParameterizedTest()
@MethodSource({"mapArgumentsProvider"})
public void mapTest(Map<Integer, String> map) {
    assertNull(map.get(0));
    assertNull(map.get(null));

    assertNull(map.remove(0));
    assertNull(map.remove(null));
    assertNull(map.remove(1));
    assertEquals(0, map.size());

    assertNull(map.put(1, "1"));
    assertEquals(1, map.size());
    assertEquals("1", map.put(1, "2"));
    assertEquals(1, map.size());
    assertEquals("2", map.get(1));
    assertEquals(1, map.size());
    assertNull(map.put(2, "3"));
    assertEquals(2, map.size());

    assertEquals("2", map.remove(1));
    assertEquals(1, map.size());
    assertNull(map.remove(1));

    assertEquals("3", map.remove(2));
    assertEquals(0, map.size());
}

@ParameterizedTest()
@MethodSource({"mapArgumentsProvider"})
public void mapSameHashCodeTest(Map<Integer, String> map) {
    assertNull(map.put(1, "1"));
    assertEquals("1", map.get(1));
    assertNull(map.put(17, "2"));
    assertEquals("1", map.get(1));
    assertEquals("2", map.get(17));
    assertEquals("1", map.get(1));
    assertTrue(map.containsValue("1"));
    assertTrue(map.containsValue("2"));
    assertFalse(map.containsValue("3"));
  assertEquals(Arrays.asList("1", "2"), map.values().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

private static Stream<Arguments> mapArgumentsProvider() {
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(new MyInternalMap<>()),
            Arguments.of(new HashMap<>())
    );
}
```

}